# $(document).width() returns different results depending on when it's called

Tags: javascript, jquery

when calling `$(document).width();` inside `$(window).load(function(){})` or `$(document).ready(function(){})` I get a different result to when I'm calling it from inside `$(window).resize(function(){})` 
the value is about 100px off so it's not because I am resizing the window, any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:
Browser: Firefox 8.0.1

Comment: Maybe because some elements are loaded / changed meanwhile?

Comment: no nothing changes and shouldn't load only be triggered after everything on the page was loaded?

Comment: Could you post an example on www.jsfiddle.com with an example

Comment: thanks @Baszz, was exactly what you were hinting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for it: I have a div inside the document that has left set to 50%. that stretches the document width. once I resize it I set left to a different value, hence decreasing the document width to the browser width - basically what Baszz was saying in his first comment